# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with Nginx and Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have just installed a fresh copy of Laravel 5 into `/var/www`.

When I browse to the server I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

My Nginx config (default) is:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

I am also confused about sites-enabled and sites-available. Where should default actually go?

I have moved default from sites-available to sites-enabled and I am now getting a 403 with "Access denied".

Comment: did you ever get this working? I have exact problem at the moment. I have googled around with no luck. Do you mind sharing your solution please?

Answer (score 4):

You probably got net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED because you hadn't told nginx what port to listen on (note the `listen 80` line in your config file), so you were trying to a port that wasn't open - hence the connection refused error.

As for `sites-available` vs `sites-enabled`, that's a Debian/Ubuntu thing to make sites easier to manage - you can have many sites configured in `sites-available`, but only run specific ones by adding a link in `sites-enabled` pointing at the respective config file in `sites-available`.

As an example, my `sites-enabled` folder has

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Feb  8 07:53 site.net -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.net
```

No copying, just a link to sites-available.

---

For your 403 error, look in your error log for what precisely is failing. It should be located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` - look for `error_log` in your main conf file to get the exact location.

Comment: Log is empty as usual.